# Django Static Image Showing then Not Showing, Views Share Base Html File Where Static Logo image is

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

My logo which is in my djangoprojectdir/static/media/ folder is showing on my homepage but in none of my other views. I dont know why it doesnt show up on other pages it shares the same base.html file for the navigation bar and header. Currently hosted website in production on digital ocean, nginx, gunicorn. I am just trying to serve static files in production debug off for small project with no database. I have already collected static. The image only works on my IndexView. My other static image files relating to my objects seem to be rendering fine. I have been exhaustively trying to figure this out.

The Image code out of the base.html that is problematic is:

```
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'maps:index' %}"><img src="static/media/Dirt logo3.png" hieght="5" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"> </a>
```

I have tried mapping with {{ MEDIA_URL }}/Dirt logo3.png and {{ STATIC_URL }} to no avail, Hardcoded would be fine if it worked.

from base.html

```
#bootstrap stuff here#
    {% load static from staticfiles %}
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'maps:index' %}"><img src="static/media/Dirt logo3.png" hieght="5" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"> </a>


{% block body %}
{% endblock %}
```

from settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite', 'maps', 'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite', 'maps', 'static', 'media')
MEDIA_URL = 'static/media/'
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "")
```

Views.py

```
# works on IndexView but not any other view
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'maps/index.html'
    paginate_by = 20
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Location.objects.all()

    context_object_name = 'location'

class NeeddirtView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'maps/needdirt.html'
    paginate_by = 20
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Location.objects.all()

    context_object_name = 'location'
```

from maps/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


app_name = 'maps'

urlpatterns = [
    # /maps/
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    # /maps/71/
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('register/', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    # /maps/companies/
    path('companies/', views.CompView.as_view(), name='comp'),
    # /maps/equipment/
    path('equipment/', views.EquipView.as_view(), name='equip'),
    #maps/
    path('equipment/<int:pk>/', views.EquipdetView.as_view(), name='equipdet'),
    path('location/add/', views.LocationCreate.as_view(), name='location-add'),
    path('location/<int:pk>/', views.LocationCreate.as_view(), name='location-update'),
    path('location/<int:pk>/delete/', views.LocationDelete.as_view(), name='location-delete'),
    path('equipment/add/', views.EquipCreate.as_view(), name='equipment-add'),
    path('equipment/<int:pk>/', views.EquipCreate.as_view(), name='equipment-update'),
    path('equipment/<int:pk>/delete/', views.EquipDelete.as_view(), name='equipment-delete'),
    path('quarry/', views.QuarryView.as_view(), name='quarry'),
    path('quarry/<int:pk>/', views.QuarrydetView.as_view(), name='quarrydet'),
    path('quarry/add/', views.QuarryCreate.as_view(), name='quarry-add'),
    path('quarry/<int:pk>/', views.QuarryCreate.as_view(), name='quarry-update'),
    path('quarry/<int:pk>/delete/', views.QuarryDelete.as_view(), name='quarry-delete'),
    path('search/', views.search, name='search'),
    path('test/', views.TestView.as_view(), name='test'),
    path('needdirt/', views.NeeddirtView.as_view(), name='needdirt'),
    path('havedirt/', views.HavedirtView.as_view(), name='havedirt'),
    path('about/', views.AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),
]
```

from urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static



urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('maps.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('maps/', include('maps.urls')),
]


urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely due to your relative path.  Try:

```
<img src="/static/media/Dirt logo3.png"... />
```

Note leading slash which makes it relative to root.

I do not like spaces in filenames, so I would change that, too.